# Given a ppt file, is it possible to save it as a template?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'm using MS PowerPoint and I would like to use a template I found in a pptx file. How can it be saved in the template library to be used later..?

Comment: Are you referring to re-saving the pptx file as a template or extracting any template on which the file was based and re-saving the "original" template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File | Save As 
Choose POTX in the Save As dialog box